# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - Push-enabled app does not open when tapping a notification

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have implemented push notifications support as provided in the IBM Worklight Getting Started training module:

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf

My problem is when the application is in the background or closed, and I receive a push notification. I click on the notification but nothing happens - the notification disappears and the application doesn't launch.

I'm using worklight 6.0.0.1 and testing on Android OS v4.1 and v2.3.

Did I miss some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the approved answer from this question: [IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Not getting Push Notifications when phone/app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581341/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-not-getting-push-notifications-when-phone-app-is-closed)

- Make sure that you did not do the same error as mentioned in it.
- Please also add the relevant push implementation of your app to the question.

Comment: It was about the application Name, because I changed and Worklight didn't recognised it. It's rubbish that Worklight identify the application by its name not a single identifier or whatever

Comment: We aim to approve this area in the future. Thanks.