# Application not opening on notification click android hyrbrid ibm-mobilefirst

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

It's an hybrid application using mobilefirst 7.1.
On iOS it is working well. But on android when clicking on the notification nothing happened (not even one log)..

Comment: 1) If the application is in foreground, does the notification appear fine?
2) Did you change the application name in strings.xml or manifest? From what MFP studio gave you?

Comment: 1) No when the application is in foreground the notification is not displayed (i think this is the basic behavior), but on background it is displaying well. 
2) Yes I changed the application name in the string.xml is this the reason ?
3) what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to Idan Adar's response to the same query at :

1) [Worklight 6.2 Android Application not launching on push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725666/worklight-6-2-android-application-not-launching-on-push-notification)

2) And 
[IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Not getting Push Notifications when phone/app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581341/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-1-not-getting-push-notifications-when-phone-app-is-closed)